# SwiftUI View Not Updating to Reflect Data Changes in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui

I've been experimenting with SwiftUI and UIKit, trying to understand how data is shared between the two frameworks, and I've created a simple example for a larger project I am working on. The example is a single SwiftUI view that contains a UIViewControllerRepresentatable wrapping a custom view controller. I am trying to have the SwiftUI view display the value of one of the view controller's properties, but it does not refresh correctly when the value is changed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewController = MyViewControllerRepresentable()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            viewController
            Text("super special property: \(viewController.viewController.data)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Increase by 1", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view = button
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        data += 1
    }
}


struct MyViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var viewController = MyViewController()

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return self.viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

When I run the app and press the button, I can see that the actual value of `data` is changing, and the publisher in `MyViewController` is firing, but the value displayed on screen is not refreshed to reflect this.

Please note, I am very new to iOS development, and this is probably an unconventional data model. However, I don't see why it shouldn't work correctly. Suggestions for a better way to share data would be much appreciated, but I would primarily like to know if it is possible to get this working with its current data structure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very good first question, well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `@Binding`. This means that when the value is updated for `data`, the views are recreated to reflect the changes.

Here is how it can be done:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var data = 3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyViewControllerRepresentable(data: $data)
            Text("super special property: \(data)")
        }
    }
}


class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @Binding private var data: Int

    init(data: Binding<Int>) {
        self._data = data
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Increase by 1", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view = button
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        data += 1
    }
}


struct MyViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var data: Int
    private let viewController: MyViewController

    init(data: Binding<Int>) {
        self._data = data
        viewController = MyViewController(data: data)
    }


    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        viewController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```